# Can we create a function that keeps the sequence's properties?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm thinking this question : consider a sequence $\{ a_n \},a_n>0,\{ a_n \}$ is decreasing , $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$, and $\{ a_n-a_{n+1} \}$ is also decreasing. Can we construct a function$ f$ that satisfies such properties: $f(n)=a_n$, $f$ is decreasing and twice differentiable, $f'<0,f''>0,\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$. In other words, create a function that turns discrete properties into continous properties.

Maybe we can use some power functions. But the sequences are undetermined, I find it hard to create such a function. But by intuition there should be such a function. What should I do ? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think this can be done. f''<0 means that f' is decreasing so f'(x)<f'(0)<0 for all x>0. So f decreases at least linearly so it must eventually cross the x axis so we can't have f>0.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. It supposed to be $f''>0$.

Comment: It's always possible, but a general method won't usually find the "nice" form you'd expect from sequences which have a simple formula.

Comment: You ask for a continuous $f$ but then talk about $f''$, so you're really asking for a twice differentiable function? Or may be a $C^2$ function?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express it clearly. Now it's corrected.

Comment: The function $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$ seems to fit, I feel at first glance.

Comment: @Piquito The function is supposed to interpolate a given sequence $a_n$.